# Found conflicting getters for name: isFocusable

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

when I sending an image in my chat system, it crash and showing this error:

```
 Found conflicting getters for name: isFocusable
```

I can store the image into firebase storage but I cant store it in firebase real-time database.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        Uri imageUri = data.getData();

        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Chats");

        final StorageReference fileReference = storageReference.child(System.currentTimeMillis()
                + "." + getFileExtension(imageUri));

        final String id = firebaseUser.getUid();
        final String key = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Chats").push().getKey();

        mUploadTask = fileReference.putFile(imageUri);

        mUploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
            @Override
            public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                    throw task.getException();
                }
                return fileReference.getDownloadUrl();
            }
        }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {

                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    String downloadUrl = task.getResult().toString();

                    final HashMap<String, Object> messageMap = new HashMap();
                    messageMap.put("Key", key);
                    messageMap.put("Sender", id);
                    messageMap.put("Receiver", userid);
                    messageMap.put("Message", downloadUrl);
                    messageMap.put("isseen", false);
                    messageMap.put("time", time);
                    messageMap.put("type", "image");
                    System.out.println("haha chat " + downloadUrl);

                    databaseReference.child(key).updateChildren(messageMap);

                }
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                System.out.println("haha chat e " + e);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

[this is my database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5x0Cs.png)

this database will generated when users enter text and send, if users are sending image, the database structure almost same, just the "type" will change it to image and the "Message" is not store text. It is store an uri like

`https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/final-year-project-51c9a.appspot.com/o/Chat%20Images%2F1551454994072.jpg?alt=media&token=6ef744f8-0a7c-42a3-b5ba-9ea660a0ec76`

Model Class

```
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;

private String Key, Sender, Receiver, Message, time, type;
private boolean isseen;

public Chat(String Key, String Sender, String Receiver, String Message, String time, boolean isseen,String type) {
    this.Key = Key;
    this.Sender = Sender;
    this.Receiver = Receiver;
    this.Message = Message;
    this.isseen = isseen;
    this.time = time;
    this.type=type;

}

public Chat() {

}

public String getKey() {
    return Key;
}

public String getSender() {
    return Sender;
}

public String getReceiver() {
    return Receiver;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return Message;
}

public boolean isIsseen() {
    return isseen;
}

public String getTime() {
    return time;
}

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setTime(String time) {
    this.time = time;
}


@Override
public int compareTo(@NonNull Chat o) {
    if (getTime() == null || o.getTime() == null)
        return 0;

    return o.getTime().compareTo(getTime());
}
```

Can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: if u need more info pls tell me

Comment: Please add the content of your model class and please also responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo pls check

Comment: do u need i add adapter class?

Comment: I cannot see the content of your model class where `isFocusable` is defined.

Comment: @AlexMamo ya, that's why i cant figured out what is the problem, i never declare a getter named isFocusable  in my life

Comment: But a field `isFocusable`?

Comment: @AlexMamo I really don't know that bro, I checked every model class that I have, none of the getter named isFocusable

Comment: @AlexMamo Btw, you build a chat system before right? can we chat in private?

Comment: Yes, I did. You can take a look [here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0Ak1HiH0tTPTJXsOEy-5v9qb). But regarding this issue, have  you also tried to search the entire project for `isFocusable`?

Comment: @AlexMamo I found it in a java class named RootMatchers and I never create it before, I think it's default

Comment: @AlexMamo your chat app is in kotlin language, sry idk about that language, btw in your chat app do u have send image feature?if in java how to do that, can u guide me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to pass those data to another method and add it into database. It should works